# Google maps and raising marker

Tags: google-maps, marker

I'm writing web app that uses google maps. I've got some points placed to the map as markers. When I drag the marker - it raises - and when I drop it - it falls back down. I want to avoid raising marker. Is there any way to drag it without raising?

Answer (score 2):

This feature has probably been added since the question was asked but stopping the marker from raising is quite straight forward now.

When creating Marker set its 'raiseOnDrag' property to false. Like so...

```
marker = new google.maps.Marker ({draggable : true, raiseOnDrag : false});
```

Comment: Note: The property is about to change to "crossOnDrag" (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefreshChanges)

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no option while creating the marker I guess there is no way.

The only thing, I could imagine would be using the icons (in the reference there is an example).
But you have to try, I don't know if selfmade icons are raised or not.

Comment: I'm using custom icons - colored arrows. In fact that's reason why I need to avoid makter raising. When I drag "UpArrow marker", it's pointer is hidden behind raised marker's body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use marker.setAnimation() method:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({...});
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'dragstart'); // trigger dragstart to keep marker in the "raised" state"
marker.setAnimation(3); // raise
// later
marker.setAnimation(4); // fall
```

In [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Animation) there are only two types of animations documented (BOUNCE and DROP), but I have discovered two more:

```
1: BOUNCE,
2: DROP,
3: raise,
4: fall
```